# dismiss current UIViewcontroller and present a new UiViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I intend to dismiss my current `UIViewController` and present to a new `UIViewController`.

I used the following code

```
 let newViewController: ViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
 self.presentViewController(newViewController, animated: false, completion: {
         self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    })
```

It gave the following error

> 2016-06-04 11:40:59.864 myApp[851:117649] Trying to dismiss the
>   presentation controller while transitioning already.
>   (<_UIFullscreenPresentationController: 0x1703e6900>)
>        2016-06-04 11:40:59.878 ePassBook[851:117649] transitionViewForCurrentTransition is not set, presentation controller
>   was dismissed during the presentation?
>   (<_UIFullscreenPresentationController: 0x1703e6900>)

Comment: dismiss the action click to dismiss the UIViewController then automatically Present anotherViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code,

Objective C Code:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:newViewController animated:NO completion:^{
    dispatch_after(0, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    });
}];
```

Swift Code:

```
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(newViewController, animated: false, completion: { () -> Void in
            dispatch_after(0, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

            })
        })
```

hope its helpful

Comment: You first need to dismiss current presented VC then only you can present another.

Answer (score 1):

Try to this code I think it's Helpfully.

OBJECTIVE-C

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:newViewController animated:NO completion:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //Run UI Updates

        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    });
}];
```

SWIFT

```
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(newViewController, animated: false, completion: { () -> Void in
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank for the reply @Ravi ..I tried your code.. It did not work.......The controller that i am instantiating is not embedded in a UINavigationCOntroller..

Answer (score 0):

You first need to dismiss currently present `viewcontroller` then after you only present another because at a time you can't present two `viewcontrollers` so, your code should be like,

```
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) { () -> Void in

        self.presentViewController(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

If you are using `navigation controller` then present or dismiss VC on `navigation controller`

**Update as asked in comment:**

Take an example,

You have three View controllers say A,B and C and currently presented viewController is C. like A - > B - > C

Now you want to dismiss C and present new D then you must make instance of B because you are dismissing C, so self means nothing. It's nil.

So you should make instance of B lets say `b` and present D on that `b`

Something like,

```
 self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) { () -> Void in

        b.presentViewController(d, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

If you are using navigation controller then it should be like,

```
   b.navigationController.presentViewCon.....
```

Comment: I tried the following code.............  It gave me the following error: Attempt to present <ePassBook.vConResult: 0x136e4ffe0> on <ePassBook.vConDetection: 0x136e4d0c0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: What happen then ?

Comment: It dismisses the current viewcontroller but did not create a new view controller........

Comment: You need to create instance of VC that is behined your presented VC and then present your view on that VC's instance. like `self.vc.presentView.....` , here vc is instance of your VC which is behind VC which you dissmiss first

Comment: Thanks @Lion ..... the above solution worked........ But it goes back to the earlier viewcontroller and then presents a new view controller..........Is there a right way to do this or is this one or this seems a hack

Comment: Once try to present newviewcontroller on mainthread if it works!

Comment: present your view in this block `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in }'